# facebook api: remove the "shared a link" when posting via api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I think there is a trick to remove the "shared a link" next the username when you post something via the facebook api. I notice it's removed when you add a message field to your post, but I would like to get it even without any message. I tried to pass TRUE, a blankspace, "&nbsp", etc as message but that was like there was no any message.

```
array(
    'message' => "      ", // I guess the trick is somewhere here
    'link' => $link,
    'name' => $name,
    'description' => ' ',
    'caption' => $date,
)
```

***what I would like:***

[image: what I would like]

***what I get:***

[image]

***with a message:***

[image]

Comment: Why would you need to remove it? It is the default “action description” Facebook uses for this kind of thing, and it _does_ describe exactly what the user did – they _shared a link_. So why would you want to mess with that?

Comment: It just looks cleaner without it.
In 2015 it's obvious that this is a link and if you have a few links like this following on a page, it looks repetitive.